# Controlling CMD default size when opened in a directory

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, cmd.exe, taskbar

When I open the CMD (By searching the executable and double-clicking it) it's opened in a small window.
When I open it using Ctrl+Shift in a directory and selecting "Open command window here" or when I run it using Win+R it's opened fullscreen, which is what I want, but slightly bigger. Instead of stopping at the taskbar like most programs do when full screen, it goes a bit more down, overlapping with the taskbar. It also goes past the right end of the screen.
When I use `start /max cmd` it again starts bigger than fullscreen.

How do I solve this?

I use Windows 8.1.

Screenshot of the bottom right of my screen:
[image: picture]
You can see the right is a bit cut and the bottom is overlapping with the taskbar.

Comment: My windows laptop is out of reach now but I remember clicking the control button on the top-left corner of CMD window and select "Defaults". That will alter the behavior of running it using Win+R or Open command window here. As of the CMD shortcut in the start menu, it's a shortcut so a separate config is associated with it, which you could edit by right-clicking on the CMD icon and pick Properties.

Comment: @ChangQian Just tried it, it doesn't help

Comment: Based on our chat on my answer, I have no idea what this can be, so I'll remove the answer.